# Return a non-temporary object from C++ function with limited life

Tags: c++, logging

I am writing a logging utility for my application. It was chosen to do so for some reasons. I want the logging to happen as

```
Logger logger;
...
logger.Info() << "This is log statement" << 1;
```

logger.Info() returns a another type (LogStream) that overloads << operator.

```
class Logger
{
public:
  Logger(LogLevel level, LogWriter writer);
  ~Logger()
  {
    // Writes to Logwrite which sends logs to all appenders
  }

template <class T>
    LogStream& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
     m_output << t;
     return *this;
    }

private:
   std::ostringstream m_output;
   LogLevel m_loglevel;
```

}

```
class Logger
{
    LogStream Info()
    {
      return LogStream(INFO, m_writer); // NOT RIGHT
    }
}
```

Is there an right and elegant way to return a logstream instance by Info() call without extra copies and has a limited life time so that appenders log (statements) without waiting till objects are out of scope.

Comment: Depends. You can use move semantics, but in this copy elision will take care of what you are trying to do.

Comment: How can you tell extra copies are performed? Did you compile with optimizations on?

Answer (score 0):

I question that you say something is not right about your code example.  The temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression, unless bound to a reference -- this seems to me like exactly the right granularity to collect log information into an atomic message and then flush.

The only thing you need to do is customize the copy constructor to *not* copy the existing buffered data, because you don't want it duplicated in the log.  Just copy the constructor parameters (the handle to the writer and the severity level).

Comment: thanks Ben. You are right, but to avoid copy on return, I return now a rvalue on Info() call using std::move. Though I should have tested with optimizations turned on as Luchian Grigore pointed out, which I will do now.

Comment: @prasadrahul: That sounds to me like you are returning a reference to a destroyed object.  Bad idea.